# What is the use of fixed keyword in setprecision while dealing with formatting of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I have seen a common programming practice to use fixed while using **setprecision**. Just wanted to know why it is used as I am new to Programming World.

Code in question:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << num1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot read this question, as it is split into 3 different places: the title, the question, and the comments. -1

Comment: is Downvoting question make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to clamp the amount of decimal digits to write.

The `setprecision(x)` call will limit it to x decimals.

More info here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: Thanks Bigiansen :)